# .IPA files from MDTool

Tags: xamarin.ios, monodevelop, mdtool

How can I make MDTool create .IPA files for my MonoTouch project?

When I build from within the MonoDevelop GUI application, .IPA files are created.

But `mdtool build --configuration:AppStore|iPhone --project:MyProject` just creates .APP files and other things.

Or does it not create a signed IPA because the user running MDTool does not have the certificates etc in their keychain?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**`mdtool build` automatically produces IPA files if this is enabled in the project settings, so you don't need to do anything special to make it happen.**

The problem in this case is that the `codesign` step which `mdtool` runs to produce an IPA file was failing with the error message "User interaction is not allowed" (it wasn't immediately obvious from the `mdtool` output that this was an error).

This, in turn, is because the `codesign` tool cannot access the keychain containing the distribution certificate and provisioning file.

To remedy this, you need to run `security unlock-keychain /Users/user/Library/Keychains/login.keychain` - or whichever keychain contains the keys.

After this, mdtool build will produce IPA files automatically.