# How to setup continuous integration for Xamarin iOS development?

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

We are developing an iOS application using Xamarin studio.Now we want to set up the Continuous integration system.Is there any good learning resources for understanding iOS development continuous integration ?

Update:
We are planning to keep the source code in bit bucket and get the continuous builds pushed into MobileIron.Please suggest what can be the best way of achieving it?
Thanks,

Ravi

Comment: Use mdtool to build project (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13210769/ipa-files-from-mdtool). Anything else could be done via CI product

Comment: We are planning to keep the source code in bitbucket and get the continous builds pushed into MobileIron.

Comment: Not a problem bitbucket is just git/mercurial hosting in the net. You could use it as your any of your local git/mercurial repositories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution we are using is with GIT Bit bucket.We are maintaining the source code in GIT Bit bucket and using the command line options for the regular code check-ins in Mac.After building the app in mac using Mobile Iron we are pushing the latest version of the app in to our corporate group of users.